# Problem at getting directory android studio kotlin on File()

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin

I cant get the directory , the IDE I am using is Android Studio using Kotlin language, I have inputted the exact path of the image directory which is "D:\Fyp\app\src\main\res\drawable\picture.jpg" , I have tried on IntelliJ with the same codes and it worked as well, but as for on android studio , it didnt work ... Below is the code ...

```
private fun encoder(): String {
    val bytes = File("D:\\Fyp\\app\\src\\main\\res\\drawable\\picture.jpg").readBytes()
    val base64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes)
    return base64
}
```

and these are the error logs ...

```
2019-12-16 20:26:24.415 15322-15322/com.example.fyp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.fyp, PID: 15322
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fyp/com.example.fyp.MainActivity}: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Fyp\app\src\main\res\drawable\image.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Fyp\app\src\main\res\drawable\image.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:159)
    at kotlin.io.FilesKt__FileReadWriteKt.readBytes(FileReadWrite.kt:63)
    at com.example.fyp.MainActivity.encoder(MainActivity.kt:62)
    at com.example.fyp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:57)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
 Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:252)
    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7255)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:482)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:159) 
    at kotlin.io.FilesKt__FileReadWriteKt.readBytes(FileReadWrite.kt:63) 
    at com.example.fyp.MainActivity.encoder(MainActivity.kt:62) 
    at com.example.fyp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:57) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to use the path of the file on your PC from your Android application.

Also, resources (anything in the `res` directory of your project) are not traditional files in your compiled application. You can't access them as files, and they might not even exist in the app after it is installed from the store (if they are filtered out based on device characteristics).

To include files in your app that you can load at run time, you need to put them in an `assets` directory, not in `res`. If you don't already have an `assets` directory, create one in `src/main`. Then put your files in it. You can read it like this:

```
val bytes = context.assets.open("picture.jpg").use { it.readBytes() }
```

Note the use of `use` wrapping the `readBytes()` call. This is to close the input stream after it's done reading. Otherwise, you leak the input stream.